# Recursive method returning a string at each step?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I have a slight algorithmic problem. I think I miss something but can't exactly figure out what.

I want to walk to a tree containing strings and get out with a unique string.

Here is a graphical example of a tree I would like to parse.

[image: tree example]

My trees would have three different types of elements :

- Boolean operators (OR, NOT, AND) => BE
- other operators (like the =) => QO
- leaves (last elements) =>LEAF

I would like to end up with something like this :

```
"LEAF QO LEAF BE LEAF QO LEAF "
```

For now, I use a recursive method: I check the current element of the tree, and re run the method on its children depending on the type of elements I have. For each step I would populate my final string.

public class SingleTest {
    static String[] booleanElements = {"or", "and", "not"};

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();

    if(true){
        String where = "";
        printWhere(tree, where);
        System.out.println(where);
    }       

}   

/*
 * Print to where tests
 */
public static boolean isBooleanElement(CommonTree t){
    return Arrays.asList(booleanElements).contains(t.toString().toLowerCase());
}


public static String printWhere(CommonTree t, String where){
    //---------------------
    // Checking node type
    //---------------------

    // Boolean Element 
    if (isBooleanElement(t)){
        // Continue parsing the tree                
        for ( int i = 0; i < t.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            printWhere((CommonTree)t.getChild(i), where+ "BE");
        }               
    }

    // Last element of tree (LEAF)
    else if(t.getChildCount() == 0 ){
        where = where + "LEAF";
    }

    // query operator
    else{
        // Continue parsing the tree    
        for ( int i = 0; i < t.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            printWhere((CommonTree)t.getChild(i), where + "QO");
        }                   
    }

    //---------------------
    return where;
}
```

My problem is that this code :

```
        String where = "";
        System.out.println(printWhere(tree, where));
```

returns "" (Which is logical due to my implementation).

So my question is, how can I get to have a non void string as final output ?

Hope this is clear enough
Thank you for your help

*Please note that this class is used for test purpose only, and I know that putting static everywhere is bad practice :)*

**EDIT :**

The problem was (as expected) due to my lack of experience with recursion.
Here is my final code :

```
public static String printWhere(CommonTree t, String where){
    //---------------------
    // Checking node type
    //---------------------

    // Boolean Element 
    if (isBooleanElement(t)){
        // Continue parsing the tree                
        for ( int i = 0; i < t.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            where = printWhere((CommonTree)t.getChild(i), where) + "BE";
        }               
    }

    // Last element of tree (LEAF)
    else if(t.getChildCount() == 0 ){
        where = where + "LEAF";
    }

    // query operator
    else{
        // Continue parsing the tree    
        for ( int i = 0; i < t.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            where = printWhere((CommonTree)t.getChild(i), where ) + "QO";
        }                   
    }

    //---------------------
    return where;
}
```

Comment: Hum, seems like there is some food for me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077216/returning-an-inorder-string-of-a-tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you method `printWhere` does not return anything! You're appending the value to new `where` string, but since Java passes parameters by value, this newly created string is thrown away when you leave the method.

Make this method return string and return `where` at the end of it. Then, concatenate the result of a recursive call with the string from the above level. That's how recursion works.

Comment: Got it, I was indeed missing this part : "Then, concatenate the result of a recursive call with the string from the above level". Thx